# PDFHummus is working when I run it from visual studio but fail when using the executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pdf-generation

I am trying to use PDFHummus to generate a pdf that shows a plot, I put all the libs and dlls in the main folder and created a very simple pdf of one page with text and an image using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// end standard library includes

// pdfwriter library includes
#include "PDFWriter.h"
#include "PDFPage.h"
#include "PageContentContext.h"
#include "PDFFormXObject.h"
#include "ResourcesDictionary.h"
// end pdfwriter library includes

using namespace PDFHummus;

int main(int argc, char** const argv) {
    // Step 1: Create a PDFWriter instance
    PDFWriter pdfWriter;
    if (pdfWriter.StartPDF("HelloWorld.pdf", ePDFVersion13) != PDFHummus::eSuccess)
        return;
    PDFPage* page = new PDFPage();
    page->SetMediaBox(PDFRectangle(0, 0, 791, 612));
    PageContentContext* cxt = pdfWriter.StartPageContentContext(page);
    cxt->DrawImage(300, 570, "avent3.pdf");
//  cxt->DrawImage(300, 570, "avent3.png");
    PDFUsedFont* font = pdfWriter.GetFontForFile("times.ttf");
    AbstractContentContext::TextOptions textOptions(font, 14, AbstractContentContext::eGray, 0);
    cxt->WriteText(30, 570, "Hello World", textOptions);
    pdfWriter.EndPageContentContext(cxt);
    pdfWriter.WritePage(page);
    delete page;


    // Step 2 Close the PDF
    pdfWriter.EndPDF();

    return 0;
}
```

I added all libs to the linker and all the includes to the c++ part of the properties, when I run it from visual studio in release mode it works fine, but when I run the executable the pdf fails to create correctly (it creates the file but is corrupted).

If I comment all the insert image lines and leave only the text it works fine
If I leave the text and insert the png file it works fine

is when I try to add the pdf vector image file that the executable stops working, but again, from visual studio it works fine. I think I am missing a dll that I have to add to the working folder but can't figure out which one

any ideas?

Comment: 1) None of those PDF functions return any error codes?  If so, you should write your code to make sure those functions were successful.  2) `pdfWriter.WritePage(page); delete page; pdfWriter.EndPDF();` -- What happens if you *don't* call `delete page;`?  As a matter of fact, you don't even need `page` to be a pointer or use `new` to create it: `PDFPage page {}; page.SetMediaBox(PDFRectangle(0, 0, 791, 612));` etc.

Comment: No errors ,but I suspect  cxt->DrawImage(300, 570, "avent3.pdf"); is what is causing the problem, when I comment that line and use  cxt->DrawImage(300, 570, "avent3.png"); instead everything works

Comment: Maybe that file cannot be found when you run it from the command line.  Also, where is the proof that there are no errors?  I don't see in the code where you are checking the return value (if there is one).

Comment: The file is definitely there in the main folder, no doubt about that.... and I try putting the  cxt->DrawImage(300, 570, "avent3.pdf");  in a try catch and did not pick up any errors.